# Google Cloud Run error: Invalid Command \"/bin/sh\": file not found when deploying from Docker image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a fairly simple Python web app with FastAPI and Gunicorn on Google Cloud Run with a Docker container following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python?authuser=0) and upon deploying I keep falling on the same error:

```
Invalid ENTRYPOINT. [name: "gcr.io/<project_id>/<image_name>@sha256:xxx" error: "Invalid command \"/bin/sh\": file not found" ].
```

It works fine to build the image and push it to the Container Registry.

On the cloud run I have set my secrets for database connection and I am passing as an argument to the Dockerfile which settings.py file to use for the production environment, as I did locally to build/run the container.

Any idea on what am I missing or doing wrong in the process? It's my first attempt to deploying a web app on a cloud service so I might not have all the concepts on point just yet.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install -y -q build-essential python3-pip python3-dev
RUN pip3 install -U pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip3 install gunicorn uvloop httptools

COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY . code/

# Pass the settings_module as an argument when building the image
ARG SETTINGS_MODULE
ENV SETTINGS_MODULE $SETTINGS_MODULE

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app --chdir /code
```

#### cloudbuild.yaml

```yaml
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ["build", "--build-arg", "SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings_production", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<image_name>", "."]
images:
- gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<image_name>
```

```sh
gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

I replaced `ubuntu:latest` (==`20.04`) with `debian:buster-slim` and it worked.

#### Previously

Deploying to Cloud Run, I receive the error too...I suspect it's the `PORT`, investigating. Not the `PORT`. Curiously, the image runs locally. Trying a different OS!

I repro'd your `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml` in a project and the build and run succeed for me:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty \
--env=PORT=8888 \
gcr.io/${PROJECT}/67486954
[2021-05-11 16:09:44 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-05-11 16:09:44 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8888 (1)
```

> **NOTE** To build from a `Dockerfile`, you need not create a `cloudbuild.yaml` and can just `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/...`

A good way to diagnose the issue is to run the `docker build` locally:

```sh
docker build \
--build-arg=SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings_production \
--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<image_name> \
.
```

And then attempt to run it:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<image_name>
```

This isolates Cloud Build as the issue and will likely result in the same error.

The error suggests that the container isn't finding a shell (`/bin/sh`) in the `ubuntu:latest` image which is curious.

I think you can|should drop the `exec` after `CMD`

> **NOTE** I read through Google's tutorial and see that the instructions include `CMD exec ...`, I'm unclear why that would be necessary but presumably it's not a problem.

Can you run the `gunicorn` command locally without issue??

```sh
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app --chdir /code
```

The placement of `--chdir /code` is curious too. How about:

```
WORKDIR code
COPY . .

...

CMD /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app
```

Hmmm [link](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html) perhaps move the `--chdir` before the `app.main:app` too so that it's applied to the `gunicorn` rather than your app.

```sh
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --chdir /code app.main:app
```

Comment: Only reason I am using the `cloudbuild.yaml` is because I couldn't figure out another way to pass the `--build-arg` command to the image build.
I tried to replace the `ubuntu:latest` with the `debian:buster-slim` and the build was successful however the URL fo the web app gave me a `Service Unavailable` so I guess the issue now might be with the port and/or db connection

Comment: I pushed the image to container registry and pulled it and tried to run it with `docker run --rm --name gcr-nobg-container -p 80:8080 --env-file .env gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<image_name>` and the command in the image is `CMD exec gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app` where the `$PORT` is the auto generated env variable in cloud run and all works fine. But it doesn't work in cloud run. I get the same `error: "Invalid command \"/bin/bash\": file not found" `. What am I missing here?

Comment: Without more information, it's not possible for me to answer. Are you confident you're using an image based on Debian rather than the troublesome Ubuntu base? What Cloud Run deployment command are you using? Perhaps create a new question and post details including your `gcloud run deploy` command?

Comment: I am using everything from the original question (`gcloud builds submit ...`) but replaced ubuntu image with debian, as you suggested.

Comment: DazWilkin, I have accepted your answer as your solution solved most of my problems. Thank you.

Comment: What is your Cloud Run command? Cloud Run is particularly sensitive to `--command` and `--args` use. Hint: if you use `--args`, you must use `--command`. If you could include your `gcloud run deploy` command (or are you using the Console?), that would help.

Comment: Currently, I've been creating new deployments manually until I got this to work. Now I'll investigate how to deploy it with a command probably from a github action and I'll keep those tips in min. Thank you!